# Bootstrap Navbar button isn't appearing

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, navbar

I can't figure out where the problem is

```
    <html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">

<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<body> 
<div class="navbar-header">
       <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Tech</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
</div>

   <div class ="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href ="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href ="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>


</body>

</html>
```

I don't see the three navigation lines button that should've appeared, instead I already see the content within li tag.

Comment: This is by design. This part is not visible on large screen due to css rule. It will be visible on small screen. Try to resize your browser

Comment: The 3 navigation lines are called hamburg menu, that will only appear on mobile devices and tabs

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned above in comments, this is the intended behavior.  If you resize your browser window manually or use your browser's developer tools to set a mobile screen size you'll see the hamburger menu instead of the full desktop menu.